# Laravel dependencies error Composer install error in Mac OSX

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I have the following error when install laravel dependencies with composer

PHP Parse error: parse error in **laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411.**

I looked at the source code of 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L411

$results = [];

I believe the reason of this is the new array syntax of php.

It seems like the library has some incompatibilities.

Below is my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
     "app/commands",
     "app/controllers",
     "app/models",
     "app/database/migrations",
     "app/database/seeds",
     "app/tests/TestCase.php"
     ]
   },
  "scripts": { 
    "post-install-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
    "php artisan key:generate"
  ]
},
"config": {
   "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're running OS X, but:

- What is your PHP version?
- How are you running your server (i.e. MAMP, plain Apache, Vagrant)?

Even without knowing the above, the line in question has the following:

```
    $results = [];
```

Meaning it's creating an array with short syntax which is only supported by PHP 5.4+. You probably have an earlier version, hence the syntax error.

I'd say update PHP if you can, or use Laravel 4.1 if you can't.

Update:

If you have a compatible PHP already installed, it's probably just a matter of pointing Composer to the proper version. Just open a new Terminal window and type `cd ~`, then create a `.bash_profile` file by typing `vim .bash_profile`. **Check the path of your XAMPP php folder** (I haven't verified the path below, it's just a *best-guess* example), and add it to the new file:

```
export XAMPP_PHP=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH="$XAMPP_PHP:$PATH"
```

Save it (esc > type :wq > enter), then reopen Terminal and try `php -v` and `which php` to see if Terminal is now using your XAMPP PHP. If not, check the path and try again!

Comment: @tbuleteler good point. but I run on php-5.5.1. Did you mean on line 411 of xxxx/helper.php is $results = [];

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, about line 411. OK, but **how** are you running PHP 5.5.1? Is it OSX's native PHP or something else? If so, what?

Comment: it is a xampp for mac osx. on mac osx is php 5.3.

Comment: php commandline (cli) is probably using the wrong php version

Comment: Composer runs the native PHP version unless you've configured your OS to do something else. Type `php -v` and `which php` in Terminal to see the version and path respectively which Composer is running on. If it's the native one, check the updated the answer to account for a possible solution.

Comment: I solved this problem. as you guys mentioned I ran a wrong php version. I run composer with a specific php version however in laravel composer.json the php system version is being used. @tbuteler is completely right.

Comment: What file did you have to change the version number in order to get things working or did you have to make the change on the server control panel? I changed my version of php from running 5.3 to 5.4 but still get this problem